# Numeric input on VF page linked to value of a Map in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, compile-error

For one of the requirements I'm building a visualforce page with a controller. The problem is that I can not save the page with `<apex:input>` type being number. Compilation error is:

> Expected input type 'text', got 'number' for Id data type

It is filled by the value(not the key) of a map in my controller.

Controller code(stripped down to wrapper only and used lines):

```
public MyWrapperClass wrapper {get; set;}
// More properties
// Constructor, other methods

public class MyWrapperClass {
    public Map<String, Integer> myMap { get; set; }
    // More properties

    public MyWrapperClass(Custom_object__c custObj, List<Custom_object_Child__c> cocs) {
        myMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for (Custom_object_Child__c coc : cocs) {
            myMap.put(coc.Unique_Name__c, Integer.valueOf(coc.Number_field__c));
        }
    }
}
```

VF page:

```
<apex:repeat var="coc" value="{!wrapper.myMap}">
    <apex:input type="number" value="{!wrapper.myMap[coc]}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Is there a workaround to this? I know I can add javascript check on the field to only allow numbers, but I'd like to try to keep javascript to a minimum.

---

P.S. Please note, that if I change the `type="number"` to `type="text"`, then the page saves without any problem.

Comment: similar issue here -- https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/51180/visualforce-compilation-error-expected-input-type-text-got-date-for-id-d

Comment: Try using a function on the controller that returns the value you want instead of trying to get it from the visualforce page.

Comment: @Aequitas can you elaborate please?

Comment: @kurunve indeed. I would even say "same issue", not just similar. But it also does not include code to reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to add

```
docType="html-5.0"
```

in your balise

```
apex:page
```

or you can use standard tag html

```
<input type="Number">
```

Hope that help.

Comment: thanks for you answer! I ended up using `<input>` tag